# Using MacBook - no option to select GoToWebinar camera in permissions (but the option was available for microphone)

Tags: macos, permission, camera

I'm trying to set up a webinar but the other participants are not able to give permission for the camera on GoToWebinar on their Macs as it doesn't appear on their list of applications that you tick. They have given permission for the microphone and are able to share screens so it is just the camera access that is missing from the options.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are they following the requirements for Mac as posted on the GoTo.com support site?

Comment: Yes. I've just been on GoTo.com support site and this is a known issue but still unresolved.

Comment: If it's a known issue with their application that there's nothing anyone here can do about it.  It has to be resolved by the developer of that application.